# Export Latex equation into vector graphic

Tags: pdf

I want to export equations from latex to import them into powerpoint (if possible as vector grafic .svg). I use windows7 / Office 2010 and sharelatex. Since I would like to export every equation, I tried:

```
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{equation}
\begin{equation}
    \dot x = f(x(t))
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    x(t_0) = x_0
\end{equation}
```

But I have no idea, how to convert the pdf into a .svg file.

Would be great, if somebody could help.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to convert into `.eps` encapsulated postscript: `MS Office 2003` (on `Windows XP SP2`) handles `.eps`. I guess that MS 2007 on Win 7 handles too :)

The conversion process:

```
pdfcrop <pdf file without ext>.pdf
pdftops -f <page number> -l <page number> -eps "<pdf file without ext>-crop.pdf" 
rm  "<pdf file without ext>-crop.pdf"
mv  "<pdf file without ext>-crop.eps" <pdf file without ext>.eps
```

Not exactly that you asked, but works fine. Oh! And you have to got a nice `cygwin`!

Comment: @user:100231 can you please help me understand how to proceed with the conversion process? Do I write the instructions in cmd? Where should the file I want to convert to eps be? Many thanks.

Comment: No, these are not Windows cmd commands. You have to use  a POSIX-compatible programming and runtime environment like cygwin (or some Linux operating system).

Comment: Windows' cmd.exe is perfectly capable of running those commands.  Only the last two will be `del` instead of `rm` and `ren` instead of `mv`.

Answer (score 1):

I would give a try to `dvisvgm` (part of TeXlive). You have to get a `.dvi` file with `latex` first and then you call `dvisvgm`.

```
% This is file t.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{equation}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    \dot x = f(x(t))
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    x(t_0) = x_0
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Then, in a shell:

```
latex t.tex
dvisvgm --no-fonts --page=1-2 t.dvi
```

This will create two files: `t-1.svg` and `t-2.svg`.

As a side note, Till Tantau, main author of `tikz-pgf`, has been working recently on a `dvisvgm` driver for `tikz-pgf`.